# Does removing Potara earrings of a fused character nullifies the fusion?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

Just give you some info about the [Potara earrings](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Potara).

> 1. *Potara Fusion* is similar to the *Fusion Dance technique*, however unlike the Fusion Dance, the Potara Fusion is **permanent**.
> 2. To use the Potara fusion, the two fusees each take one of the two earrings and put them on opposing ears. The two will automatically merge as soon as the earrings are put on.

After the fusion is done, the fused character has 2 earrings on each side of their ears, neither in the Anime nor the Manga has shown that fused character remove the Potara earrings. This makes me wonder what happens when fused character like *Vegito* remove one or two of the earrings, will they be separated? Or still permanently fused forever?

[image]

Comment: i assume it wouldn't revert otherwise Old Kai and Kaibito would have done it by now. remember that Old Kai's been fused with an old woman for hundreds of years

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, removing the earrings does NOT nullify the fusion.

Source - http://universaldragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Potara_Earrings

Quote from the wiki -

> The earrings have the ability to fuse two people into a single entity, substantially enhancing the abilities of both individuals. The resulting fusion lasts forever, even if the fused being removes the earrings. However, there is one instance where the Potara Fusion will be nullified and restore the fused being back to their original forms, which is when they are sucked into an environment that would not support it (as seen with Vegito being absorbed inside Buu).

Edit: I've found a quote of Elder Kaioshin, stating that the Potara earrings are meant to be eternal-lasting.

> Context: Elder Kaioshin gives the Potara to Goku Elder Kaioshin: “Here! Put
>   this Potara on your left ear! [ ] Put the other one on Gohan’s ear.
>   Just by doing that, you two will be able to merge together! Like with
>   Fusion.” Goku: “Huh! Re-really!?” Elder Kaioshin: “Of course. And
>   what’s more, the effect is greater than with Fusion! This has been the
>   trump card treasure of the Kaioshins since long ago.”

source - Chapter: 501 (DBZ 307), P6.2-6

> Context: Goku asks how long Potara-based fusion lasts
>   Elder Kaioshin: "The Potara don't have such a weakness. It's eternal! You'll never return to normal again!"

source - Chapter: 501 (DBZ 307), P11.6

Edit 2 -
As jphager2 has mentioned in the comments below, after using the Potara Earrings, they can then be removed & re-used to fuse 2 new people, we've never been given information about the possibility of 2 fusions being able to fuse, and the only information I can find on it is speculation.

Comment: Switch over to referencing the episodes. Old Kai, Old Kai and Kibito, as Memor mentions.  And add a picture!

Comment: Hmm... It seems like an answer to me. **But!** It did not stated in the *original* source, the quote was apparently a fan theory. I was hoping for a *real* answer, either theory or what, as Axelrod said, referencing to the episode like Memor-X did, it's more convincing that the quote from the wiki. But anyways, I will upvote your answer, I'm hoping for an edit soon :)

Comment: @HappyFace I've edited my answer to provide quotes with sources.

Comment: Seems to me. The earrings could be used again and again, fusing more poeple into a single body.

Comment: @jphager2 We don't see any fusions fuse, but we do see multiple sets of fusions.  Perhaps this can be touched on in Super.

Comment: @HappyFace And now it's done!